# Parse json & html data from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm sending ajax request to url and getting following response:

**Ajax Request:**

```
<div id="htmldata"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://testing.local/index.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
            // Parse response here ...
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Response:**

```
<div class="dataset">
    <h1 class="title">List of Data</h1>                             
    <table width="100%" align="center" class="datatable" >
        <tr>
            <td class="dataField" ><label>Data 1</label></td>
            <td class="dataValue">Value 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="dataField" ><label>Data 2</label></td>
            <td class="dataValue">Value 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="dataField" ><label>Data 3</label></td>
            <td class="dataValue">Value 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

{"status":"success", "message":"Received data successfully"}
```

In ajax response, there is both types of data, json and html.

So I want to alert success or failer message from json data and set html code in div with id "htmldata" using jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Is this json string always on the last line of your response?

Comment: yes it always in last line, but json data may be different.

Comment: var responsetext = response.split("\n"); alert(responsetext[responsetext.length -1]); Try this Or you could use javascripts last index of.

Comment: i suggest just stick to one, which is `JSON`, just add another inside: `data: "rest of markup html"`

Comment: I already thought about it, but this time situation is different that's why I want to do this

Comment: @yogeshsuhagiya what is the situation?

Comment: html code is generated through view file

Comment: @yogeshsuhagiya share your `index.php` codes

Comment: http://testing.local/index.php is dummy url, it's just for example to explain my question

Comment: Ran into same problem today. Couldn't find any solution as of now. I dont think I will be able to call AJAX back to back, after first ajax is completed successfully

Answer (score 3):

Make you json object like this:

```
$form = '<div class="dataset">
         <h1 class="title">List of Data</h1>                             
         <table width="100%" align="center" class="datatable" >
    <tr>
        <td class="dataField" ><label>Data 1</label></td>
        <td class="dataValue">Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="dataField" ><label>Data 2</label></td>
        <td class="dataValue">Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="dataField" ><label>Data 3</label></td>
        <td class="dataValue">Value 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>';

// Handle Success Message
echo json_encode(array( 'status'=>'success', 
                        'message'=>'Received data successfully', 
                        'html'=>$form));
// Handle Failure Message
/*echo json_encode(array( 'status'=>'fail', 
                        'message'=>'Something went wrong', 
                        'html'=>$form));
*/
```

In both `success` and `fail` situation its return you the form,
Now Javascript Turn:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://testing.local/index.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.message);
        console.log(response.html);
    }
});
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close to what you want

```
var respJson;
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url : "http://testing.local/index.php"
  dataType : "html",
  dataFilter : function(data, type) {
    var dara = split(data, "\n");
    respJson = jQuery.parseJSON(dara.pop());
    return join(dara);
  },
  success: function(response) {
    // respJson contains your json
    // response is your html
  }
})
```

Or you could simply include the json as a string in the response header.

Answer (score 0):

In the parsing part, you could test if the response is json via trying to parse it and get results. If the response is not json, then print out the html response. I would suggest you to make a specific element for hosting the dynamic html, which comes from your AJAX call.